# application stops working after clicking on button

Tags: java, android, android-studio, crash

My application stops working right after clicking on the Login or Register button on the start screen.

This is my Login Activity:

```
package com.mypackage.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MaterialEditText email, password;
    Button btn_login;

    FirebaseAuth auth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Login");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        btn_login = findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String txt_email = email.getText().toString();
                String txt_password = password.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(txt_email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(txt_password))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "All fields are required!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(txt_email, txt_password)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful())
                                    {
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the Start activity

```
    package com.mypackage.app;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        Button login, register;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

            login = findViewById(R.id.login);
            register = findViewById(R.id.register);

            login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override


 public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });

        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this is the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mypackage.app">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".StartActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".StartActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".StartActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I´m using build gradle version 3.1.4 and google-services version 4.2.0.

Dependencies are:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
```

When I click on the Register button, this is the log I get:

```
11-04 19:38:05.313 2055-2055/com.mypackage.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mypackage.app, PID: 2055
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mypackage.app/com.mypackage.app.RegisterActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2779)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2844)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6361)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        at com.mypackage.app.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.java:37)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6675)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2844) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6361) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

Comment: please post your logcat error

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari like I said I am not able to post it because the app won´t run on the simulator.

Comment: You are using firebase authentication but don't have the Internet permission in your manifest. Add Internet permission and try again?

Comment: @Nero Unfortunatelly it didn´t help :(

Comment: Without the error log, it's difficult to help you. Connect your phone to your computer and that should allow you to access the error log?

Comment: @Nero When I try to run emulator, the log is still putting this error on screen: <br> 11-04 09:51:46.158 3111-3111/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory) <br>
11-04 09:51:46.158 3111-3111/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2

Comment: @Nero I connected my phone and I edit this post, you can find log error there :)

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari I added logcat :)

Comment: My  guess is that the problem is in your layout file, where you have declared an standard toolbar instead of a  android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar, check it, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your error log, the problem is related to your XML file where you've added your toolbar element. 
From looks of it you seem to be using

> android.widget.Toolbar

in your XML, but in your java code you are importing

> android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

which is a different type. Change your XML toolbar to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar and it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me, it worked perfectly! Next time I will try to be more careful.